# Distributed Connector in Cluster System, failing to connect snowflake server: While registering the schema to start REST API

Tags: rest, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connector, snowflake-schema

```
                    $ tail -f connect-distributed.log
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector.validate(SnowflakeSinkConnector.java:234)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:375)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$1(AbstractHerder.java:326)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748), errorCode:1001 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector:236)
                [2021-10-27 10:23:06,752] INFO AbstractConfig values: 
                 (org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig:354)
                [2021-10-27 10:35:06,406] ERROR Validate: Error connecting to snowflake:
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Exception: Failed to connect to Snowflake Server
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Error Code: 1001
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Detail: Snowflake connection issue, reported by Snowflake JDBC
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Message: JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Exception encountered for HTTP request: Connect to XXXXX.XXXXX.snowflakecomputing.com:443 [XXXXX.XXXXX.snowflakecomputing.com/XX.XX.XX.XXX, XXXXX.XXXXX.snowflakecomputing.com/XX.XXX.XXX.XXX, XXXXX.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/XX.X.XXX.XX] failed: connect timed out.
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.RestRequest.execute(RestRequest.java:284)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.core.HttpUtil.executeRequestInternal(HttpUtil.java:496)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.core.HttpUtil.executeRequest(HttpUtil.java:441)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.core.HttpUtil.executeGeneralRequest(HttpUtil.java:408)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.newSession(SessionUtil.java:586)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.core.SessionUtil.openSession(SessionUtil.java:284)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.core.SFSession.open(SFSession.java:435)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initialize(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:104)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initializeConnection(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:79)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.initConnectionWithImpl(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:116)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.<init>(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:96)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver.connect(SnowflakeDriver.java:164)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1.<init>(SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1.java:68)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceFactory$SnowflakeConnectionServiceBuilder.build(SnowflakeConnectionServiceFactory.java:75)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector.validate(SnowflakeSinkConnector.java:234)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:375)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$1(AbstractHerder.java:326)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.co``ncurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748), errorCode:1001 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector:236)
                [2021-10-27 10:35:06,408] INFO AbstractConfig values: 
                 (org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig:354)

            This error is in the distributed connector logs while registering the REST API through CURL. Please help as how the registration can happen successfully. As Error code: 1001 is really not understandable

            My curl command is as below:
            curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8083/connectors' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{
                "name": "file-stream-demo-distributed",
                "config": {
                    "connector.class": "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector",
                    "tasks.max": "1",
                    "topics": "uat.product.topic",
                    "snowflake.topic2table.map": "uat.product.topic:TestKafkaTable",
                    "buffer.count.records": "10000",
                    "buffer.flush.time": "60",
                    "buffer.size.bytes": "5000000",
                    "snowflake.url.name": "XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443",
                    "snowflake.user.name": "kafka_connector_user_1",
                    "snowflake.private.key": "XXXXX",
                    "snowflake.database.name": "KAFKA_DB",
                    "snowflake.schema.name": "KAFKA_SCHEMA",
                    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
                    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
                    "value.converter": "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeJsonConverter",
                    "value.converter:schemas.enable": "true",
                    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081"
                }
            }'
```

Output of Curl : {"error_code":500,"message":"Request timed out"}

```
               Below is the connect-distributed.properties:
                                     key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
                 value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
               rest.port=8083
               topic=uat.product.topic
               offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
               status.storage.topic=connect-status
               status.storage.replication.factor=1
               config.storage.topic=connect-configs
               config.storage.replication.factor=1
               offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
               offset.storage.replication.factor=1
               key.converter.schemas.enable=true
               value.converter.schemas.enable=true
               group.id=connect-cluster
               bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
```

Please let me know where I am doing wrong in my settings. As at properties file, else while doing the curl. As this is getting executed in the master node of the 3 node cluster. As this is defined in the master node. Nothing in the other 2 nodes. Please help how to resolve this error. Do I need to configures something else even.

Comment: The error says your nodes are not able to reach Snowflake. This could be due to a network issue, proxy in between, etc. Are you able to run [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) to see if the connectivity from nodes to Snowflake is ok?

Comment: As its UAT system, I don't have the provision of the SnowCD to get install. Any other method to check the same, please.

Comment: I think SNOWSQL will also do the task of connecting remote system. But I don't have the install authority

Comment: What about a simple curl like this: *curl -v https://<account>.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com* ?

Comment: $ curl -v https://XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.snowflakecomputing.com:443
* About to connect() to XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.snowflakecomputing.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying XX.XX.XX.XXX...
* Connection timed out
*   Trying XX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
* After 86333ms connect time, move on!
*   Trying XX.X.XXX.XX...
* After 43166ms connect time, move on!
* Failed connect to XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.snowflakecomputing.com:443; Operation now in progress
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX.snowflakecomputing.com:443; Operation now in progress

Comment: Ok, that shows a connectivity issue. This is not really related to Kafka connector, but just to connectivity. Are you sure your nodes have access on the internet? Maybe you have a proxy in between that filters traffic and Snowflake URL is not whitelisted? Can you reach other websites, like Google for example? **curl -v https://google.com**

Comment: You are correct they have limited connections to the applications to internet as the google even not reachable $ curl -v google.com
* About to connect() to google.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 172.217.9.206...
* Connection timed out
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4004:832::200e...
* Failed to connect to 2607:f8b0:4004:832::200e: Network is unreachable
* Failed connect to google.com:80; Network is unreachable
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2607:f8b0:4004:832::200e: Network is unreachable

Comment: How to make the port enabled, how 443 port can be enabled. As over here for snowflake database as a service()

Comment: This needs to be done in AWS servers

Comment: For ports, services, whitelisting etc of Snowflake entities, it needs to be done on the cloud layer where SF is deployed which is one of AWS,Azure or GCP.

Comment: no no, we want to access the snowflake from our internal systems which are already on aws. Which we want to connect with the snowflake system. So how we can enable this in our AWS system we are already using?

Comment: You probably want [Privatelink](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-privatelink.html) to be enabled.

Comment: True, I want this private link of snowflake to be opened in the another aws servers of ours